# What are some real life examples of UCS (Uniform Cost Search)

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, searching

Studying search algorithms I've been fascinated by UCS and its similarity to the Djikstra algorithm in some cases. Has anyone any real life example of a possible use of this UCS algorithm to solve some real world problems?
(Apart from the obvious ones that Computer Science students see while studying Djikstra).

Comment: Actually one really cool place I learned these types of search algorithms are used is in the context of planning problems with PDDL, where instead of searching a more physical space like a maze, it searches in the space of possible actions to see which one gets to a goal the fastest. (which admittedly sounds obvious when you say it that way but I remember thinking that was really cool when I learned about it in my AI class, since to me the planning problems didn't really feel like the same kind of problem)

Comment: @StephenDonovan that is exactly what I was thinking about too, robot arm pddl (strips and so on) programming is one of the most fascinating branches of AI. But apart from that what do you think would be other interesting real life scenarios for this kind of algorithms?